# iOS application distribution issue

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to create .ipa file of my first iOS application to test in anther device which doesn't connect to my Mac. I have two certificates from my Mac account for distribution and development. But when I try to archive it is saying I don't have a relevant certificate. I try to download it any add it to Xcode but downloaded file is not selectable. As suggest in other threads in here I try to delete expired certificates but I don't have any.

I try to add both development certificates from Xcode system preferences but it displays as those certificates are revoked.

I will add all relevant screenshots here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm using Xcode 6.2. If you need more information please let me know. Can anyone help me to get rid of this error? Any help or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you own the developer account or are you a team member on an account being managed by someone else?

Comment: Is that a typo, or are you actually using Xcode 6.2? I'm asking because I remember some "pain" after I upgraded to Xcode 8 - and my ADC membership was renewed in August. I recall needing to (a) remove all expired provisioning profiles I could, (b) regenerate one profile that was needed via ADC, (c) remove all app-specific  in Xcode, (d) import all profiles it found, and finally, (e) check off the "Automatically signing" along with setting me as the team member. I remember the WWDC session about Xcode 8 and code-signing and I think my issues were mostly due to the new process they have.

Comment: @BSMP Account is managing by someone else. But I have information.

Comment: @dfd Yes I'm using xcode older version due to my situation I cannot upgrade it now